# Is /dev in linux virtual?

Tags: linux, dev

Today at work a client had `rm -rf /dev` and ended up deleting two files in `/dev/shm` that forced his site to no longer work.

From what I learned previously `/dev` is not virtual, but a fellow technician had suggested to reboot the server because `/dev` is virtual like `/proc`. Sure enough I rebooted the server and the files that the client rm -rf'd were there.

So, my question is; is `/dev` virtual? Is it the kind of virtual like `/proc`? Is there more documentation on this? How can I restore the `/dev` files without a server reboot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for a very long time has been "sort of".

Currently the Linux device tree is managed by [`udev`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), a userspace device manager which replaced devfs several years ago. udev populates /dev with any device nodes the system needs, depending on the rules configured in its configuration files.

On the newest Linux systems, /dev is in a temporary RAM disk provided by [`devtmpfs`](http://lwn.net/Articles/330985/). You could call these virtual.

Example:

```
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=6109940k,nr_inodes=1527485,mode=755)
```

The only reason for actual device nodes in /dev nowadays is for the boot environment, before udev has started. Typically only `/dev/console` and `/dev/null` are needed in the actual filesystem, which is sufficient to get to the point where udev can be started. It will then provide everything else.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it's virtual, just that it's autopopulated by the system.

Comment: True. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @user973917 You could run `udevadm control --reload` or just restart `udevd`.

Comment: `/dev/shm` is a separate thing. Files in there are not created by udev, but they *are* temporary (not meant to survive a reboot).

Comment: @AlanCurry What's this about `/dev/shm`? Nobody's mentioned that at all.

Comment: It's mentioned in the first line of the question

Comment: @AlanCurry Oh, you're right. I was so focused on the basic question that I missed that little detail.